# Math.floor() | 0

Tags: javascript, math

I have often seen this in JavaScript:

```
var val = (myvar / myothervar) | 0;
```

Which as far as I understood was one of the many shortcuts to floor a value in JavaScript (like `~~`, and `>> 0`, etc). However, I was looking at a piece of code recently that did this:

```
var val = Math.floor(myvar/ myothervar)|0;
```

They used `Math.floor()` and then also did a bitwise OR with `0`. The author did this many times, so it wasn't just a typo they did once. What do you gain by doing both?

For the curious, the code I am referring to can be found [here](https://github.com/chrisdickinson/collide-2d-tilemap/blob/5842f95f5d22fb3ce4741d1189cc7881510226d5/index.js#L35)

Comment: Perhaps this was designed to treat `Infinity` as `0` in the case that `myothervar` is `0`? For example, when simulating gravity between two points (`G*m/r^2`), it might be preferred to assume no gravitational force between two simultaneous points (when `r=0`) than attempt infinite gravity.

Comment: @apsillers: Nice example, but it would still be better to check if r is arbitrarily small. Dividing by `5e-324` is not particularly desirable either

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might not have thought of:

- `Math.floor(NaN) == NaN` (ok, not really, but `Math.floor(NaN)` is `NaN`)
- `Math.floor(NaN) | 0 == 0`

Also relevant for `Infinity`

As pointed out by @apsillers, this is probabably to eliminate `Infinity`s:

```
var x = 1;
console.log(Math.floor(1 / x));      // 1
console.log(Math.floor(1 / x) | 0);  // 1
x = 0;
console.log(Math.floor(1 / x));      // Infinity
console.log(Math.floor(1 / x) | 0);  // 0
```

Comment: Why bother `Math.floor`ing it though?

Comment: Because all those floor short cuts don't take into account  numbers over 32-bits. Compare `Math.floor(Number.MAX_VALUE)` with `Number.MAX_VALUE | 0`, anything above a 32-bit int will be wrong using any of the bitwise shortcuts because they operate on 32-bits even if the int is larger than that, but `Math.floor` will account for it properly. You can see the same results with `1099511627776` which is 2 to the 40th power.

Comment: I know this is an old post but... Math.floor(x) | 0 still has the same 32 bit conversion? Math.floor(Number.MAX_VALUE) | 0 == Number.MAX_VALUE | 0. Which means Math.floor doesn't really do anything here right?

Comment: @david Math.floor rounds down, and the OP example includes negative numbers, so -1.3 becomes -2 ... on the other hand, bitwise |0 goes towards *zero*. But in the usecase, why is it applied to a Math.floor? Math.floor can return a NaN, which may not be desired. |0 forces even a NaN to int (0 in that case).